# C++ memory management for local arrays with fixed size not known at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, memory-management

In a member function of a class I want to process an array which I pass as a pointer. The size n of the array is not known at compile time but stays fixed once the class instance is initialized. During processing in foo I create another array (isNull) that also has the size n and which is needed for further processing.

```
class myClassA {
private:
    const int n; // Not known at compile time
public:
    myClassA(int n) : n(n) {}

    void foo(int* arr) { // Function that processes array arr (size n)
        bool* isNull = new bool[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            isNull[i] = arr[i] == 0;
        }
        // Do more stuff

        delete[] isNull;
    }
};
```

Although the code works, I have doubts that this is an efficient solution if foo is called quite often because every call memory for isNull has to be allocated and deallocated in the heap.

I tried two other methods for solving this. In myClassB, I defined an upper limit (MAXN) for n. This way I do not have to reserve memory dynamically. However, every function call I reserve more memory on the stack than I acutually need, which does not seem really elegant to me and it also limits n.

```
class myClassB {
private:
    const int n; // Not known at compile time
    static const int MAXN = 100; // Upper limit of n (for all instances of the Class)
public:
    myClassB(int n) : n(n) {}

    void foo(int* arr) { // Function that processes array arr (size n)
        bool isNull[MAXN];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Only use n entries of isNull
            isNull[i] = arr[i] == 0;
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }
};
```

Another way of doing this might be to define isNull as a member variable. This way I only have to allocate memory once in the constructor and I can reuse it. However, for large classes this can get quite messy and I hesitate to declare many member variables which I only need in one function.

```
class myClassC {
private:
    const int n; // Not known at compile time
    bool* foo_isNull; // Variable used in foo
public:
    myClassC(int n) : n(n), foo_isNull(new bool[n]) {}
    ~myClassC() { delete[] foo_isNull; }

    void foo(int* arr) { // Function that processes array arr (size n)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Only use n entries
            foo_isNull[i] = arr[i] == 0;
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }
};
```

Declaring isNull as static does not work since multiple instances of the class have other n values.

What is the best way to deal with this in C++?

**Edit**

I did some testing and for `n = 10` and `10^7` calls of `foo` I got runtimes of:

2.221s for `myClassA`

0.346s for `myClassB`

0.220s for `myClassC`

I also tried a solution using vectors (as local variables and as member variables) which resulted in significantly higher runtimes.

As a result I opted for option B, since it offers reasonably fast performance and it does not mess up the member variables too much. Also in contrast to option C it allows `foo` to be marked as `const` as it does not modify anything from the class.

Comment: Just use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which is C++'s resizable array type. The guideline for code in current C++ is to avoid new/delete if you can. see [C++ core guidelines R.11](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete) which kind of fails to mention to use containers if you can.

Comment: I think the actualy memory allocation problem would still be the same. Every function call the vector within the function would reserve new memory for the entries and release it after it goes out of scope. Would this not lead to the same issue as stated in above?

Comment: just pass the `isNull` array as a function parameter by reference (please use `std::span`), make the allocation someone else's problem, he could just preallocate it on the stack before passing it.

Comment: what is `do more stuff` ? What do you need the array for?

Comment: Since `isNull` is only used in `foo` I would like to avoid to handle it outside of it, if possible.
The `do more stuff` requires `isNull` multiple times and as whole array, so I can not process it index-by-index, unfortunately.

Comment: *"Would [std::vector] not lead to the same issue as stated in above?"* Yes, but it would at least elminiate a whole bunch of other problems, such as `myClassC` lacking a proper copy/move constructor/assignment, which will give you crashes/leaks in some usage scenarios.

Comment: Also conveniently `std::vector` never shrinks the underlying memory block unless you very explicitly request it, which means you just need to store a vector somewhere and `.clear()` it before very use, and everything will just work.